# Internet stops working, "Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device"

Tags: networkmanager

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04. After running the system for a while the wireless internet will stop working.

Dutifully, I run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But this returns the message:

```
Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device
```

But I have *lots* of space available on the hard disk, in RAM, and via swap. What's going on?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=894483), it turns out that the [Crashplan](https://www.code42.com/crashplan/) back-up service is the most likely culprit. It uses many inotify watches and, eventually, eats them all up.

The immediate fix is to run:

```
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```

To make more watches available.

The long-term fix is to edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` to include the line:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

**Edit**: It's been a few days now, and the problem hasn't arisen since I performed the above.

Comment: Are there any updates - is the fix still working?  Or is there a Crashplan bug that needs addressing?  Thanks!

Comment: @GilesB: I have not had a problem with my internet since, so I believe this solved the problem. It would be handy if Crashplan checked this value and alerted the user to potential problems before they arose.

Comment: The solution described above remains the recommended solution on CrashPlan's support site:

https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Linux_Real-Time_File_Watching_Errors

Comment: as up to date the problem still exist and the `max_user_watches` hasn't solved it unfortunately

Comment: may `sudo sysctl -p` will help.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc